# When I open new tab I read "chrome://new tab"

Tags: google-chrome

Tomorrow when I open new tab I read "chrome://new tab". What is that? is dangerous? How can I remove this?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that starts with "chrome://" comes from the browser itself rather than another website. So don't worry about it it shouldn't bother you at all.

Answer (score 1):

The url "chrome://newtab" means a new tab opened by chrome itself.
It is secure and configurable which can be modified in `Settings -> On startup`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a URL. It is just a shortcut for a new tab for Google Chrome.